Issue with Saving Yarn Cache on Self-Hosted Runner with Setup-Node action
Currently, I'm encountering a problem with saving the Yarn cache using the setup-node action.
The error:
Failed to save: Unable to reserve cache with key 
node-cache-macOS-yarn-33259bc05a9ff84ddf70121c6ada6b7886b9a8e9721b785469c879d852cc411e, 
another job may be creating this cache. More details: Cache already exists.

Code:
- name: Use Node.js
  uses: actions/setup-node@v4
  with:
     node-version: '20.15.1'
     cache: 'yarn'

Action version: 4
Platform: macOS
Runner Type: self-hosted
Tools version:

Node version: 20.15.1
Yarn version: 1.22.22

When I use a hosted runner, it works normally.
